# Prolog: finding a list that does not satify a goal

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search, goal-tracking

If I have a list of edges for a problem like "Show me the routes from a city that is considered dangerous to one that is considered safe" as so...

```
dangerous(oakland).
safe(portland).

move(rome,plane,portland).
move(portland,plane,rome).
move(halifax,train,gatwick).
move(gatwick,car,rome).
move(portland,plane,newyork).
move(oakland,plane,rome).
move(oakland,plane,gatwick).
move(halifax,train,gatwick).
move(gatwick,plane,rome).
move(oakland,train,newyork).
```

I can get a list of Paths that lead to a safe city by using the following depth first search(found on SO)...

```
dfs_start(Start, Goal, Path) :- phrase(dfs(Start, [], Goal), Path).

dfs(Node, _, Goal)   --> [Node], { call(Goal, Node) }.
dfs(Node0, Es, Goal) --> [Node0],
        { move(Node0,_,Node1), \+ member(Node1, Es) },
        dfs(Node1, [Node0|Es], Goal).
```

The problem I'm trying to solve however is to find all of the Paths from dangerous cities that do NOT lead to a safe city (which in this case would only be one oakland -> newyork.)
If I call the above function with...

```
dfs_start(oakland,safe,Path).
```

...I get

```
Path = [oakland, rome, portland] ;
Path = [oakland, gatwick, rome, portland] ;
Path = [oakland, gatwick, rome, portland] ;
```

...but what I'm looking to do is call something like...

```
dfs_start(oakland,unsafe,Path).
```

...and get...

```
Path = [oakland, newyork] ;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why "only one `oakland->newyork`"? What's wrong with `oakland->rome`? How's `rome` different from `newyork`?

Comment: rome can eventually lead to portland, which is a safe city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem description is ambiguous, maybe that's the cause of your doubt.
As I understand it, `unsafe(X).` is plainly wrong, because eliminates each filtering condition. You could try to simplify the rule in this way (I've commented out the inefficient rule, you can delete it):

```
% unsafe(X) :- findall(Y,safe(Y),SafeList), member(X,SafeList), !, fail.
unsafe(X) :- \+ safe(X).
```

**Edit** the comment you exchanged with Will Ness clarified a bit the task: the stop condition must be true when the path cannot be extended more, and any safe city is banned from path. I simplified a bit the code, removing unnecessary features, so you can concentrate on the logic: graph is acyclic, so the visited path is not required, and instead of passing down a Goal, just use the required statement:

```
unsafe_path([Start|Path]) :-
    dangerous(Start),
    phrase(dfs(Start), Path).

dfs(Node) --> [Node1],
   {  move(Node, _, Node1),
      \+ lead_to_safe(Node1)
    } -> dfs(Node1) ; {true}.

lead_to_safe(Node) :- safe(Node).
lead_to_safe(Node) :-
    move(Node, _, Node1),
    lead_to_safe(Node1).
```

test:

```
?- unsafe_path(P).
P = [oakland, newyork].
```

if we add a fictious city the path is extended:

```
?- assertz(move(newyork,train,turin)).

?- unsafe_path(P).
P = [oakland, newyork, turin].
```

if we make turin a gateway to a safe city:

```
?- assertz(move(turin,train,portland)).

?- unsafe_path(P).
P = [oakland].
```

Comment: Hrmmmm. I agree with you that my problem description is ambiguous. I'm racking my brain to try to figure this out. What I need is any path list where the tail city could never be connected to a safe city. does that make it any more clear?